# Qt Insert two different QGraphicsWidgets in the same QGraphicsScene, setZValue is invalid

Tags: c++, qt

Calling `collidingItems` when two `QGraphicsWidget`s are visible overlapping, but returns null

`QGraphicsWidget0`, `QGraphicsWidget1` inherit from `QGraphicsWidget`.
Eventually I see that `icon1` is shown on top, how can I get `icon1` to show on the bottom without changing the insertion order?

```
icon0= new QGraphicsWidget0();
icon1= new QGraphicsWidget1();
scene.addItem(icon0);
scene.addItem(icon1);
icon1->setZValue(-1);
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: what is `Icon`?? it might be one class that inherits QGraphicsItem and what is `central_icon` . code that you attach didn't help us to understand what you want

Comment: I agree with @Parisa.H.R . I think there needs to be a bit more code here to give context so others can help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys, I have solved the problem, I had set `QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent` on some icons causing the other icons to look like `setZValue()` was not working.